# Why does a Keras model object's predict method not allow batch size of 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've trained a fine-tuned ELMo model using Keras that will only predict with a `batch_size` of `2`. Here's some example code:

```
model_input = np.repeat(np.array([str(user_input)]), 2)
model.predict(model_input, batch_size=2)
```

This code runs perfectly fine. However, if I run this:

```
model_input = np.array([str(user_input)])
model.predict(model_input, batch_size=1)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlu/nlu_classifiers/elmo_scratch.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "nlu/nlu_classifiers/elmo_scratch.py", line 61, in main
    model.predict(model_input, batch_size=1)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1169, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 294, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/mjs/anaconda3/envs/nlucp36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input must be a vector, got shape: []
         [[{{node lambda_1/module_apply_default/StringSplit}}]]
```

Why is this? And is there a way to predict on a single example without having to use `np.repeat`? It's not a huge problem because it's basically the same speed, but it's been annoying me for a little while.

Comment: Can you add an example of "user_input" and model architecture such that we can replicate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`np.repeat()` wraps `np.array([str(user_input)])` in an array but you are not calling `np.repeat()` when your batch_size is 1 so `model_input` is a 1D array instead of a 2D array. Try this:

```
model_input = np.array([[str(user_input)]])
model.predict(model_input, batch_size=1)
```